# jQuery select all inputs under ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select all input checkboxes in li under a specific ul?

I have:

```
<ul id="something">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$('ul li input[type=checkbox]')`

Here is a working example, you can see that the `console.log` will show only input's a, b, d (because c's type is not checkbox).

```js
checkboxes = $('ul li input[type=checkbox]')

checkboxes.each(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="something">
    <li>
        <input name="a" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="b" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="c" type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="d" type="checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ID selector for your UL like this:

```js
var checkboxes = $("#something li input[type=checkbox]");

checkboxes.each(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="something">
    <li>
        <input name="a" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="b" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="c" type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="d" type="checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="not-these">
      <li>
        <input name="a-no" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="b-no" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="c-no" type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="d-no" type="checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will let you get all the input's html

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery( "ul#something li" ).each(function( index ) {
        var html = jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').html();
        console.log(html);          
        });
    });
```

Comment: Fixing the code after seeing my answer is really **NOT** nice!

Comment: You forgot to mention that your original code was `jQuery(this).find('input').html();`, which will not get the checkboxes

Comment: @Dekel : you forgot to see that in his html code there is no other element apart from `input type="checkbox"`, then why won't this get the value?

Comment: In this case - why would you change the code after viewing my answer? And regarding the question - your original answer does not give the solution since it doesn't get the input checkboxes inside ul li (which is the question).

Comment: @Dekel : If you are in doubt that my code won't run, try it out yourself. Now, about using type selector... was just to improve my answer which not necessarily was wrong.